How to customize the input element with a conditional class based on an error state inside v-select Vue library
I try to put class 'has-error' based on condtion and handle vaildation message for that v-select but i don't know how achieve that
https://vue-select.org/
<v-select
      v-model="add.city"
      :options="currentCities"
      :label="$store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' ? 'nameAr' : 'nameEn'"
      :placeholder="$t('addresses.addCity')"
      required
      class="select porder-radius-5 text-gray input_fixed-height"
      :class="{ 'text-align-right': $store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' ,  'has-error': errors.has('addAddressForm.city') }"
    > </v-select>

I have tried to handle that using Scoped slot but nothing happen
 <v-select
      v-model="add.city"
      :options="currentCities"
      :label="$store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' ? 'nameAr' : 'nameEn'"
      :placeholder="$t('addresses.addCity')"
      required
      class="select porder-radius-5 text-gray input_fixed-height"
      :class="{ 'text-align-right': $store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' }"
    >
      <template #search="{ search, attrs, events }">
        <input
          type="search"
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="events"
          class="vs__search"
          :class="{ 'has-error': errors.has('addAddressForm.city') }"
        />
      </template>
 </v-select>


Try adding CSS like this : <style> .has-error { --vs-border-color: red; } </style>

where does errors come from, how is it updated, and most importantly, is it reactive?

I'm finding mixed reports of whether using multiple class binds on one component is really supported; switching over to one of the officially supported ways of using multiple classes might solve this issue, e.g. array syntax: :class="['vs__search', { 'has-error': errors.has('addAddressForm.city') }]"


Make sure errors is reactive. For example wrap it in reactive:

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
const reactiveErrors = reactive(errors)
</script>


Make a computed function with errors.has('addAddressForm.city'):

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
const errorClass = computed(() => reactiveErrors.has('addAddressForm.city'))
</script>


Call this computed function in your bidden class:

<template>
<input
  :class="{ 'has-error': errorClass }"
  />
</template>

